# Firebase: Complex tasks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Lets take a common task **Creating document and attaching images to it.**

Right now I can only do it in two requests. One will upload images take their url and then with second request I will add this urls to my new document, there can be variation in order but I CANT make less than two requests for this task. 
And this is most basic case.

Editing document with attached images is more difficult task. 
We need to get document data, then we need to update it with new one, upload new images and delete images which was deleted and then edit document accordingly.
It is not rocket science but it is done on the client device. And here comes my question.

**Can we make it easier for client code?** Can we make this tasks in one request and move all this backend code to firebase?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in two requests? Have you actually profiled your code to observe it being slow or otherwise inefficient?

Comment: What will happen if client connection will be lost in between some of the request, we have to make special checks for this. I'm not saying this is wrong. I'm asking is there a way to make it easier for client code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I Understand the problem . But currently what you are asking for is a specific use case where you want to use both Firebase Database as well Firebase Storage . From current SDK perspective these are two different modules . So to suffice your requirement from client only code two calls should be there . But you might worry about transactional integrity if these are two separate calls . If you really want to club them in single call . Use functions to expose a rest api that takes file attachment . So from function you can simply do both jobs (uploading/saving) . Once done you can reply the needed information in the response of the rest api .

Comment: Is there any examples or documentation how to do it? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api this one doesn't helped me much.